# How would I calculate months backward from a date within one variable in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I searched a lot to find an answer. I can get a lot of answers to count date difference between two dates. But struggling to find an answer that count difference within a variable.

I have a data with customerID and puchase_date in MS SQL Server. I want to get the data of Customers who purchased within last 12 months from the recent date(counting 12 months backwards from Max(Purchase_date). I created a dummy data. The alphabets are customerID

My data look like this:

Customer_ID-    Purchase_date

a   -23/12/2018

a   -25/06/2018

a   -28/07/2015

b   -12/11/2018

b   -30/01/2012

b   -18/05/2018

c   -17/05/2014

c   -18/02/2018

c   -25/12/2018

d   -21/10/2018

d   -21/10/2016

d   -20/10/2014

e   -20/10/2018

r   -30/09/2018

f   -23/05/2018

f   -23/07/2017

f   -12/03/2014

t   -20/04/2018

t   -20/04/2016

c   -22/02/2018

s   -11/03/2018

s   -08/11/2017

v   -05/07/2018

n   -04/04/2017

l   -13/06/2016

p   -23/08/2017

q   -19/11/2017

z   -22/09/2016

x   -03/09/2015

g   -07/04/2017

The output I am expecting is as below:

CustomerID  -     Purchase_date

a             -    25/06/2018

b              -    18/05/2018

c-  18/02/2018

f   -23/07/2017

Comment: I'm guessing purchase data isn't a `DATE` datatype?

Comment: Sorry. Purchase_date is a date datatype

Comment: why wasn't v included in the expected results? or s?

Comment: It would be useful if you indicate the table definition and also the query you have run.

Comment: @scsimon that is because I don't have anything to count backwards

Comment: So you just want all rows where the purchase was within 12 months of the most recent purchase by anybody? I am really struggling to understand the requirements here.

Comment: @Sean Lange exactly.

Comment: @jpcooper I was trying the following code                                                                                                       select CustomerID,max(purchase_date), datediff(MM,Max([purchase_date]),-12), 
from [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
group by customerID
order by CustomerID

Comment: You should update your question with that. You can write inline code by enclosing it with backticks, and you can also put it on separate lines by prepending those lines with four spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty vague but I think you simply need something like this.

```
select Customer_ID
    , Purchase_Date
from YourTable
where Purchase_Date > dateadd(month, -12, (select max(Purchase_date) from YourTable))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Purchase_Date needs to be less than the max purchase date for the customer as well, example results don't include the row with the max date. Also the sub select needs to join to the outer table on customer_Id